# How to add certain data from csv file to ArrayList

Tags: java, csv, sorting, arraylist, filereader

I have three *.csv files and I'm using an interface to compare the objects.

My question is: how to add only certain data to an array list?

For example, I only need `items[1]` which is `yearID`, `items[2]` which is `teamID`, `items[11]` which is `homeRuns`, and `items [12]` which is `RBI` value.

How to add them into an `arrayList` while still making them a value in the `Batter` class, and then passing the array list to another class? Here is the first two lines of the file

### Batting.cvs

playerID    yearID  stint   teamID  lgID    G   AB  R   H   2B  3B  HR  RBI SB  CS  BB  SO  IBB HBP SH  SF  GIDP
abercda01   1871    1   TRO NA  1   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

**Batter.java**
`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Batter extends Player{
    private  int YearID;
    private String TeamID;
    private int HomeRuns;
    private int RBI;

    
public Batter(int yearID, String teamID, int homeRuns, int rBI) {
    super();
    YearID = yearID;
    TeamID = teamID;
    HomeRuns = homeRuns;
    RBI = rBI;
}


Batter() throws Exception{
ArrayList<String>  battingData= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> masterData= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> pitchingData= new ArrayList<String>();

Scanner myScan1= new Scanner(new File("Batting.cvs"));

while(myScan1.hasNext()) {
    while(myScan1.hasNext()) {
        battingData.add(myScan1.nextLine());
        String line= myScan1.nextLine();
        String items[]= line.split(",") 
        
    for( int i= 0; i<battingData.size(); i++){
        battingData.add(new Players(Integer.parseInt(items[0]));
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Players.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Players {
    private ArrayList Player[];


public Players (String BatData, String PitData,String MasterData) {
    
}
}
```

Comment: Please update your question and provide an example of CSV input (file). Also, please avoid pasting unnecessary code parts, such as getters/setter, or multiple empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

A few important points. You were looping myScan1.hasNext() twice unnecessarily.
You were also discarding one line as you were calling nextLine twice.
I have proposed below a suggestion of how you can achieve what you want.

```
while (myScan1.hasNext()) {
  String line = myScan1.nextLine();
  battingData.add(line);
  String items[]= line.split(",") 

  for( int i= 0; i<battingData.size(); i++){
    String yearID = items[1];
    String teamID = items[2];
    String homeRuns = items[11];
    String rbi = items[12];

    // do what you need to do with these variables
  }
}
```